# "Restore Default Settings" on Huawei P9 Lite

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, huawei

After I started my Huawei P9 Lite for the first time, after I completed the first boot setup, it asked me the following question:

[image]

What does it mean? It is the first time I run Android M ever and never encountered such a question before.

Answer (score 1):

*I think it is related to Google backup. If you setup your Google account then this option asks you to restore your backup : phone numbers, apps as well as settings, such as APN, WiFi passwords, and so.*

***UPDATE*** : 
I've found that the step for restoring defaults is a part of the setup process and it is optional. You will be asked about restoring all default settings. Just tap ***Do not allow***.

- [Source](http://www.geeksquad.co.uk/articles/huawei-p9-lite-user-manual-setup-guide), 22th step.

Comment: Hmm, possible. Where does *default* sit in it?

Comment: @SarpSTA Oh sorry, I misunderstood. English being my 3rd language. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! I want to stress it that this information is good for me. Thank you! But I wish to learn what it does.

Comment: It does what it says: restore to default. Can be helpful if you made mistakes settings up the device, e.g: connecting a wrong Google account.

Comment: But why right after the initial settings?

Comment: Good question. Maybe you should ask Huawei.

Comment: I actually did. I hope they'll reply. One weird sidenote: It doesn't ask the question when you don't log into a Google account upon start.

Comment: Then my  guess was correct.

Comment: Likely. I have been able to concluded that this question only pops up if a Google Account has been logged in during first setup. Since it annoyed me, I factory reset the phone and didn't log into Google during setup.